# linux command stuck

Tags: files

I have strange problem on my Linux machine

When I do the following simple command

```
 chmod +x  /tmp/file
```

chmod is stuck and not returned the prompt

what could be the problem?

- the same issue when I run other commands as **cp** or **ls –ltr**

Comment: While executing this command, in second tab, run the command `top`. See which process is eating your CPU

Comment: Do you have a NFS mounted system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an I/O error or corrupt filesystem (if `/tmp` is a separate filesystem).

In case of a separate filesystem: Unmount it and run `fsck`. Otherwise check the kernel log (`dmesg | tail -n 25`) and SMART  (`smartctl -a /dev/sda`) for I/O errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Debian it was the NFS-server interfering somehow. `chmod` on some files took forever.

`journalctl -xr` had no entries, `smartctl -a <drive>` was fine (brand new drives), `fsck` reported `clean`.

There might be sweeter-natured ways but `systemctl stop nfs-kernel-server.service` did it for me.